# How to update only one object with vue.set

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I have an array with companies like this:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "firstname": "lorem",
    "lastname": "ipsum",
    "name": "something",
    "subscription": "premium",
    "active": 1
}]
```

The companies are displayed in a layout and when I click on one of them it triggers:

```
lockCompany(id, index) {
    Vue.set(this.companies, index, {active: 0});
}
```

But.. when I set active to 0 it removes firstname etc.. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be either (if you properly use `:key=item.id` in your `v-for` template):

```
Vue.set(this.companies[index], 'active', 0);
```

... or (otherwise):

```
let newCompany = Object.assign({}, this.companies[index], { active: 0 });
Vue.set(this.companies, index, newCompany);
```

As it stands, you just rewrite an element of your array with completely new object each time `Vue.set` is called.

Comment: Quick question, why do I need :key=id for? Right now I get the index with `v-for="(company, index) in companiesCheck"` Should I change this?

Comment: Not sure what companiesCheck is (it's not shown in your example), but yes, usually using `:key` is an optimal strategy. Check [this section of official documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) for details.

Comment: I can't seem to get it working.. I've changed the key to `v-for="company in companiesCheck" :key="company.id"` and trigger the function with `@click="lockCompany(company.id)"` and changed vue set to `Vue.set(this.companiesCheck[id], 'active', 0);` But I get a error: `Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'active' in undefined`

Comment: You seem to confuse `id` and `index` here. Instead of passing `company.id` so that you have to look up for specific element in an array, just pass `company` as a whole instead, then update it. Like this: `lockCompany(company);`, and then `Vue.set(company, 'active', 0)`.

Comment: Thank you! I tried deleting a company with vue.delete but with no success. Now I use `Vue.delete( this.companies, index );`. If you know a better solution I would love to hear:)

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the item in the companies array at a position of 0 to `{ active : 0 }`

You probably just want to do

```
lockCompany(id, index) {
    Vue.set(this.companies[index], 'active', 0 );
}
```

That will just set the `active` property to 0 instead.